# Binomial distribution with exponentially many terms and exponentially small success probability

Tags: probability, limits, probability-distributions, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Consider the following Binomial distribution,
$$
N \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(e^{nA}, e^{-nB}),
$$
In other words, it's a Binomial distribution with exponentially many terms and exponentially small success probability. We also know that $A > B$. What I'm struggling to show is that for $s>0$,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[N^s\right] \doteq e^{ns(A-B)},
$$
where the dot equality notation $a_n \doteq b_n$ denotes equality in the exponential scale for two positive sequences $\left\{a_n\right\}$ and $\left\{b_n\right\}$, implying that the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of $\frac{1}{n} \log \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ tends to zero.

Does anyone have any idea how to prove this? I attempted to demonstrate that the probability of observing the expectation tends to one, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: Binomial is discrete, where are you guaranteeing that $e^{nA} \in \mathbb N$? **EDIT**: Also I think it would be better to write $A > 0 > B$ since otherwise $e^{-nB}$ would not be a valid probability.

Comment: @Gregory I think we need $B>0$ for $e^{-nB}$ to be a probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(m, p)$, from the Markov inequality we have for $s>0$

$$\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X^s\right]}{(np)^s} \ge \mathbb{P}(X^s\ge (mp)^s)=\mathbb{P}(X\ge mp) \ge \mathbb{P}(X\ge \text{med}(X)) \ge \frac{1}{2}.$$

Moreover, we know that $X$ has a sub-Poisson distribution, that is:

$$\mathbb{M}_X(t)=(q+pe^t)^m \le \exp (mp(e^t-1)).$$

This implies that for every $s>0$ (see Corollary 1 of [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167715221002662) or Higher moments section in the [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) for more details):

$$\mathbb{E}\left[X^s\right] \le (mp)^s \exp \left (\frac{s^2}{2mp} \right ).$$

Hence, we get the bounds:

$$\log \frac{ 1}{2} \le \log \frac{ \mathbb{E}\left[X^s\right]}{(mp)^s} \le \frac{s^2}{2mp},$$

which implies the desired result after setting $p=e^{-nB}, m= e^{nA}$ with $A>B>0$, dividing by $n$, and taking the limit as $n \to \infty $.